# Net-SNMP, error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant

Tags: c++, c, autotools, net-snmp, mingw-w64

Trying to compile the Net-SNMP library in windows with Mingw64 thru a MSYS shell... I am following the instructions inside README.win32

> ./configure --prefix="$BASEDIR" \
>         --with-mibdirs="$BASEDIR/share/snmp/mibs" \
>     --with-mib-modules="agentx disman/event-mib winExtDLL
>   examples/example"\
>           --disable-embedded-perl --without-perl-modules \

After running `make`
I get the following error after a little while

> ../../include/net-snmp/config_api.h:98:0,
>                    from ../../include/net-snmp/net-snmp-includes.h:76,
>                    from mibII/at.c:94: ../../include/net-snmp/library/vacm.h:42:20: error: expected identifier or '(' b efore numeric constant
>
> #define VIEWSTATUS 7
>
> make[2]: *** [mibII/at.lo] Error 1
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory /home/net-snmp-5.7.3/agent/mibgroup
>
> make[1]: *** [subdirs] Error 1
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory /home/net-snmp-5.7.3/agent'
>
> make: *** [subdirs] Error 1

This is the file containing the line of the error

```
    #ifdef __cplusplus
extern          "C" {
#endif

#define VACM_SUCCESS       0
#define VACM_NOSECNAME     1
#define VACM_NOGROUP       2
#define VACM_NOACCESS      3
#define VACM_NOVIEW        4
#define VACM_NOTINVIEW     5
#define VACM_NOSUCHCONTEXT 6
#define VACM_SUBTREE_UNKNOWN 7

#define SECURITYMODEL   1
#define SECURITYNAME    2
#define SECURITYGROUP   3
#define SECURITYSTORAGE 4
#define SECURITYSTATUS  5

#define ACCESSPREFIX    1
#define ACCESSMODEL 2
#define ACCESSLEVEL 3
#define ACCESSMATCH 4
#define ACCESSREAD  5
#define ACCESSWRITE 6
#define ACCESSNOTIFY    7
#define ACCESSSTORAGE   8
#define ACCESSSTATUS    9

#define VACMVIEWSPINLOCK 1
#define VIEWNAME    2
#define VIEWSUBTREE 3
#define VIEWMASK    4
#define VIEWTYPE    5
#define VIEWSTORAGE 6
#define VIEWSTATUS  7

#define VACM_MAX_STRING 32
#define VACMSTRINGLEN   34      /* VACM_MAX_STRING + 2 */

    struct vacm_groupEntry {
        int             securityModel;
        char            securityName[VACMSTRINGLEN];
        char            groupName[VACMSTRINGLEN];
        int             storageType;
        int             status;

        u_long          bitMask;
        struct vacm_groupEntry *reserved;
        struct vacm_groupEntry *next;
    };

#define CONTEXT_MATCH_EXACT  1
#define CONTEXT_MATCH_PREFIX 2

/* VIEW ENUMS ---------------------------------------- */

/* SNMPD usage: get/set/send-notification views */
#define VACM_VIEW_READ     0
#define VACM_VIEW_WRITE    1
#define VACM_VIEW_NOTIFY   2

/* SNMPTRAPD usage: log execute and net-access (forward) usage */
#define VACM_VIEW_LOG      3
#define VACM_VIEW_EXECUTE  4
#define VACM_VIEW_NET      5

/* VIEW BIT MASK VALUES-------------------------------- */

/* SNMPD usage: get/set/send-notification views */
#define VACM_VIEW_READ_BIT      (1 << VACM_VIEW_READ)
#define VACM_VIEW_WRITE_BIT     (1 << VACM_VIEW_WRITE)
#define VACM_VIEW_NOTIFY_BIT    (1 << VACM_VIEW_NOTIFY)

/* SNMPTRAPD usage: log execute and net-access (forward) usage */
#define VACM_VIEW_LOG_BIT      (1 << VACM_VIEW_LOG)
#define VACM_VIEW_EXECUTE_BIT  (1 << VACM_VIEW_EXECUTE)
#define VACM_VIEW_NET_BIT      (1 << VACM_VIEW_NET)

#define VACM_VIEW_NO_BITS      0

/* Maximum number of views in the view array */
#define VACM_MAX_VIEWS     8

#define VACM_VIEW_ENUM_NAME "vacmviews"

    void init_vacm(void);

    struct vacm_accessEntry {
        char            groupName[VACMSTRINGLEN];
        char            contextPrefix[VACMSTRINGLEN];
        int             securityModel;
        int             securityLevel;
        int             contextMatch;
        char            views[VACM_MAX_VIEWS][VACMSTRINGLEN];
        int             storageType;
        int             status;

        u_long          bitMask;
        struct vacm_accessEntry *reserved;
        struct vacm_accessEntry *next;
    };

    struct vacm_viewEntry {
        char            viewName[VACMSTRINGLEN];
        oid             viewSubtree[MAX_OID_LEN];
        size_t          viewSubtreeLen;
        u_char          viewMask[VACMSTRINGLEN];
        size_t          viewMaskLen;
        int             viewType;
        int             viewStorageType;
        int             viewStatus;

        u_long          bitMask;

        struct vacm_viewEntry *reserved;
        struct vacm_viewEntry *next;
    };

    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    void            vacm_destroyViewEntry(const char *, oid *, size_t);
    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    void            vacm_destroyAllViewEntries(void);

#define VACM_MODE_FIND                0
#define VACM_MODE_IGNORE_MASK         1
#define VACM_MODE_CHECK_SUBTREE       2
    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    struct vacm_viewEntry *vacm_getViewEntry(const char *, oid *, size_t,
                                             int);
    /*
     * Returns a pointer to the viewEntry with the
     * same viewName and viewSubtree
     * Returns NULL if that entry does not exist.
     */

    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    int vacm_checkSubtree(const char *, oid *, size_t);

    /*
     * Check to see if everything within a subtree is in view, not in view,
     * or possibly both.
     *
     * Returns:
     *   VACM_SUCCESS          The OID is included in the view.
     *   VACM_NOTINVIEW        If no entry in the view list includes the
     *                         provided OID, or the OID is explicitly excluded
     *                         from the view. 
     *   VACM_SUBTREE_UNKNOWN  The entire subtree has both allowed and
     *                         disallowed portions.
     */

    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    void
                    vacm_scanViewInit(void);
    /*
     * Initialized the scan routines so that they will begin at the
     * beginning of the list of viewEntries.
     *
     */


    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    struct vacm_viewEntry *vacm_scanViewNext(void);
    /*
     * Returns a pointer to the next viewEntry.
     * These entries are returned in no particular order,
     * but if N entries exist, N calls to view_scanNext() will
     * return all N entries once.
     * Returns NULL if all entries have been returned.
     * view_scanInit() starts the scan over.
     */

    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    struct vacm_viewEntry *vacm_createViewEntry(const char *, oid *,
                                                size_t);
    /*
     * Creates a viewEntry with the given index
     * and returns a pointer to it.
     * The status of this entry is created as invalid.
     */

    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    void            vacm_destroyGroupEntry(int, const char *);
    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    void            vacm_destroyAllGroupEntries(void);
    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    struct vacm_groupEntry *vacm_createGroupEntry(int, const char *);
    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    struct vacm_groupEntry *vacm_getGroupEntry(int, const char *);
    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    void            vacm_scanGroupInit(void);
    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    struct vacm_groupEntry *vacm_scanGroupNext(void);

    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    void            vacm_destroyAccessEntry(const char *, const char *,
                                            int, int);
    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    void            vacm_destroyAllAccessEntries(void);
    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    struct vacm_accessEntry *vacm_createAccessEntry(const char *,
                                                    const char *, int,
                                                    int);
    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    struct vacm_accessEntry *vacm_getAccessEntry(const char *,
                                                 const char *, int, int);
    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    void            vacm_scanAccessInit(void);
    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    struct vacm_accessEntry *vacm_scanAccessNext(void);

    void            vacm_destroySecurityEntry(const char *);
    struct vacm_securityEntry *vacm_createSecurityEntry(const char *);
    struct vacm_securityEntry *vacm_getSecurityEntry(const char *);
    void            vacm_scanSecurityInit(void);
    struct vacm_securityEntry *vacm_scanSecurityEntry(void);
    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    int             vacm_is_configured(void);

    void            vacm_save(const char *token, const char *type);
    void            vacm_save_view(struct vacm_viewEntry *view,
                                   const char *token, const char *type);
    void            vacm_save_access(struct vacm_accessEntry *access_entry,
                                     const char *token, const char *type);
    void            vacm_save_auth_access(struct vacm_accessEntry *access_entry,
                                     const char *token, const char *type, int authtype);
    void            vacm_save_group(struct vacm_groupEntry *group_entry,
                                    const char *token, const char *type);

    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    void            vacm_parse_config_view(const char *token, const char *line);
    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    void            vacm_parse_config_group(const char *token,
                                            const char *line);
    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    void            vacm_parse_config_access(const char *token,
                                             const char *line);
    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    void            vacm_parse_config_auth_access(const char *token,
                                                  const char *line);

    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    int             store_vacm(int majorID, int minorID, void *serverarg,
                               void *clientarg);

    NETSNMP_IMPORT
    struct vacm_viewEntry *netsnmp_view_get(struct vacm_viewEntry *head,
                                            const char *viewName,
                                            oid * viewSubtree,
                                            size_t viewSubtreeLen, int mode);


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif                          /* VACM_H */
```

I have tried taking the line #define VIEWSTATUS 7 out which has resulted in a different error.

> mibII/vacm_vars.c: In function 'init_vacm_vars':
>
> mibII/vacm_vars.c:106:10: error: 'VIEWSTATUS' undeclared (first use in this func
>   tion)
>
> {VIEWSTATUS, ASN_INTEGER, NETSNMP_OLDAPI_RWRITE,
>
> mibII/vacm_vars.c:106:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once
>    for each function it appears in
>
> mibII/vacm_vars.c: In function 'var_vacm_view':
>
> mibII/vacm_vars.c:518:10: error: 'VIEWSTATUS' undeclared (first use in this func
>   tion)
>
> case VIEWSTATUS:
>
> make[2]: *** [mibII/vacm_vars.lo] Error 1
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/net-snmp-5.7.3/agent/mibgroup'
>
> make[1]: *** [subdirs] Error 1
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/net-snmp-5.7.3/agent'
>
> make: *** [subdirs] Error 1

Of course it cannot find the VIEWSTATUS macro I just commented out.
As I understand it there is some issue perhaps with namespace? but I have done a search of the source code of Net-SNMP 5.7.3 and cannot find the macro VIEWSTATUS anywhere else but where is defined and where is used in the latter error above.
What is going on here? Any ideas are welcomed...

Comment: `VIEWSTATUS` is an `enum`definition in one of the MS Windows OLE headers - In case you pull that in along some obscure `#include `chain, there's your error.

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense thank you very much for your answer.. I just changed the macro to something else and it got thru this point.